# Best way to feed which(,arr.ind=T) back into matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have extracted the array indeces of some elements I want to look at as follows:

```
mat = matrix(0,10,10)

arrInd = which(mat ==0,arr.ind = T)
```

Then I do some more operations on this matrix and eventually end up with a vector or rows `rowInd` and a vector of columns `colInd`. I want us these indeces to insert values into another matrix, say mat2. But I can't seem to figure out a way to do this without looping or doing the modular arithmetic calculation myself. I realize I could take something like

```
mat2[rowInd*(colInd-1)+rowInd]
```

In order to transform back to the 1-d indexing. But since R usually has built in functions to do this sort of thing, I was wondering if there is any more concise way to do this? It would just seem natural that such a handy data-manipulation  function like `which(,arr.ind=T)` would have a handy inverse.

I also tried using `mat2[rowInd,colInd]`, but this did not work.

Comment: I guess the underlying representation in memory of a matrix is not 2 dimensional? The rows and columns are just attributes of the matrix?

Comment: @zheyuan Li: thanks for your response. I should have noted that after the manipulations, my row indeces and column indeces were stored as separate vectors. But thanks to your repsonse, it seems obvious now that what I needed was `mat2[cbind(rowInd,colInd)]`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read on [R intro: indexing a matrix](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Index-matrices) on the use of matrix indexing. `which(, arr.ind = TRUE)` returns a two column matrix suitable for direct use of matrix indexing. For example:

```
A <- matrix(c(1L,2L,2L,1L), 2)
iv <- which(A == 1L, arr.ind = TRUE)

#     row col
#[1,]   1   1
#[2,]   2   2

A[iv]
# [1] 1 1
```

If you have another matrix `B` which you want to update values according to `iv`, just do

```
B[iv] <- replacement
```

Maybe for some reason you've separated row index and column index into `rowInd` and `colInd`. In that case, just use

```
cbind(rowInd, colInd)
```

as indexing matrix.